# The action 'destroy' could not be found for SampleformsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to delete my data in database I got this error:

```
Unknown action
The action 'destroy' could not be found for SampleformsController
```

My controller destroy action code looks like this:

```
def destroy
  @sampleform = Sampleform.find_by_id(params[:id])

  if @sampleform.destroy
    redirect_to sampleforms_path
  end
end
```

again I got that same error

again I got that same error

Comment: Do you get the error you posted when using the code you posted? Your code has syntax errors. Try using `@sample_form = Sampleform.find_by_id(params[:id])`, and `redirect_to sampleforms_path`

Comment: searched here for same issue - in my case, had accidentally placed the destroy definition under a `private` block in the controller - so even though defined, it wasn't being registered by rails as a valid action endpoint. posting here only in case it helps anyone else..

Answer (score 3):

In your `SampleformsController`, you need to add a `destroy` method:

```
class SampleformsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    # destroy your record here
  end
end
```

You can find more information on this topic [in the Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions).

Answer (score 0):

**Action**

The bottom line here is that you need to have the `destroy` action in your `SampeFormsController`:

```
#app/controllers/sample_forms_controller.rb
class SampleFormsController < ApplicationController
   def destroy
     @sample_form = SampleForm.find params[:id]
     @sample_form.destroy
   end
end
```

I think the specific issue you have is that you're calling the following:

```
Sample form.
```

This will **not** work - it's syntactically incorrect. Whenever you call a `model` (which is just a [Ruby class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html)), you need to use [`CamelCase`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). As a model name is a constant, it means you need to call it correctly - which would be as follows:

`SampleForm.destroy params[:id]`

--

**Names**

It must be noted that Ruby / Rails permits you to include arguments in function names without brackets.

Variables & other references (CONSTANTS, Models) should *never* have a space - this is the primary issue you have, apart from not having the `destroy` action present

Answer (score 0):

in your `destroy` method you had define `@sample form` remove space or put `_`. your Model name is also not appropriate.. Your `destroy` method should be like below:

```
def destroy
     @sample_form = SampleForm.find(params[:id])
     @sample_form.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sample_forms_url }
    end
end
```

I hope it helps you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

class SampleformsController < ApplicationController
def destroy
   @sampleform =Sampleform.find(params[:id])
   @sampleform =Sampleform.destroy
end

before do this step on your controller first you check all validation process completed in your models

because sometime any error in validation this process show this error